# Exchange web services - find all unread messages with soap xml request

Tags: go, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

in my app I need to query Echange web services server and find all unread messages. I am using Golang and I am sending soap xml requests. I tried the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
    xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" />
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <m:FindItem
            Traversal="Shallow">
            <m:ItemShape>
                <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
            </m:ItemShape>
            <m:Restriction>
                <t:IsEqualTo>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:IsRead" />
                    <t:FieldURIOrConstant>
                        <t:Constant Value="false" />
                    </t:FieldURIOrConstant>
                </t:IsEqualTo>
            </m:Restriction>
            <m:ParentFolderIds>
                <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox" />
            </m:ParentFolderIds>
        </m:FindItem>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

but in this case I get error saying that my request is incorrect. If I remove `<t:IsEqualTo>`, I get all messages in my inbox. Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the list of FieldURI Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/fielduri#fielduri-attribute), `item:IsRead` should be `message:IsRead`. Below is the example copied from [Equality filter in EWS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-use-search-filters-with-ews-in-exchange#equality-filter-in-ews)
:

```xml
<t:IsEqualTo>
  <t:FieldURI FieldURI="message:IsRead" />
  <t:FieldURIOrConstant>
    <t:Constant Value="false" />
  </t:FieldURIOrConstant>
</t:IsEqualTo>
```